# AsyncTask.execute() Safety

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm using `AsyncTask.execute(Runnable run)` for short statements that require non-UI thread executions on a legacy project. But it's well known that AsyncTasks should not be kept as anonymous, local, and inner class declarations to avoid memory leaks.

How safe is to trust in this approach? I prefer to use it to short statements, but when I realize I'm referencing it as anonymous I got concerned about the leak possibility. Lint doesn't warn anything about it as it would when dealing with based AsyncTasks classes construction.

Comment: make your var final,or declare them inside your asynchronous task

Comment: that should be post as the answer ^

Comment: @Eminem what var? I just need to use in one statement os two, which require non-ui execution.

Comment: variables, asynchronous tasks are private

Answer (score 2):

AsyncTasks are fine, so long as they terminate in a relatively short time frame.  The reason people say to avoid them is that ANY thread, AsyncTask or not, will keep a reference to its parent and to any variables it holds as class variables around.  That reference goes away when the thread finishes execution.  So as long as the task or thread runs in a reasonable amount of time it isn't a worry.